# Why is apply() not called ?

Tags: scala

When I run below code apply method is not being called :

```
object Tester2 {

  def apply(){
    println("apply")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Tester2
  }
}
```

But if I use `Tester2()` in main method instead of `Tester` the apply method is then called

Why is () required in order for the apply method to be invoked ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tester2` is an object name, a value. Expression may contain only single value. You could replace `Tester2` with `2` or `"str"`.

`Tester2` is an expression with result type `Tester2.type`. Just like `2` is an expression with result type `Int`.

To call `apply` method you should add brackets like this:

```
Tester2()
```

You could call `apply` method explicitly without brackets:

```
Tester2.apply
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Tester2`, you are getting a Tester2 object.   When you call `Tester2()`, you are calling the apply method for the Tester2 object.  Scala needs the '()' to disambiguate between creating a new object or calling apply() when using syntax sugar as `Tester2()`.

Comment: Thanks Senia.   Since this is an object/singleton, "getting" is more apt than "creating"   I updated my answer.